# Strange if statement behavior

Tags: java, arrays, io

I wrote this code to print out a list of names and scores and store which name and score has the highest and lowest score. The part of the code that looks for high scores works. However, the part that stores the low scores gets overwritten with higher scores. I can't seem to figure out why this happens.

```
        for (int z = 0; z < studentCount;z++)
        {
        System.out.print(StdList[z].getName()+ "\t\t\t" + StdList[z].getScore1() + "\t    " + StdList[z].getScore2() + "\t       " + StdList[z].getScore3() + "\t  " + StdList[z].getTot()+"\n");
        ave3 = ave3 +  StdList[z].getTot();
        if (StdList[z].getTot() > scoreHigh)
        {
            nameHigh = StdList[z].getName();
            scoreHigh = StdList[z].getTot();
        }
        if (StdList[z].getTot() < scoreLow);
        {
            nameLow = StdList[z].getName();
            scoreLow = StdList[z].getTot();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code before posting the question? What are the results? Can you provide test data to replicate the problem as well?

Comment: You have a `;` at the end of your `if`.

Comment: How are nameHigh/nameLow etc. declared?  static variables, class variables, or method variables?  I've had some odd behavior boil down to a programmer thinking they were writing to class variables, but were actually writing to method variables.

Comment: @resueman that result is part of proper debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As resueman says in the comments, the problem is you have a `;` in your low if statement

```
if (StdList[z].getTot() < scoreLow);
```

This will end the if statement and the code below that sets the lower scores will always be executed just in a different scoping block

Comment: There's a reason to close for simple typos...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza while it might have been a typo, I think it's important to explain why the semi colon affected things so much

Comment: Then use any of the 100s of duplicates.